# Tensorflow - How to use tf.gather() to deliver part of the first layer's inputs to one of the next layer's filter

Tags: python, tensorflow

Let's say I have this setup:

```
conv1 = tf.layers.conv2d(
    inputs=input_layer,
    filters=4,
    kernel_size=[14, 14],
    padding="valid",
    activation=tf.nn.relu
    )

conv2 = tf.layers.conv2d(
    inputs=conv1,
    filters=16,
    kernel_size=[5, 5],
    padding="valid",
    activation=tf.nn.relu
    )
```

Like the partial connection scheme in [this paper](http://journals.tubitak.gov.tr/elektrik/issues/elk-16-24-3/elk-24-3-40-1311-58.pdf), I want to deliver separate numbers of layers from `conv1` to one filter in `conv2`. Do I use `tf.gather()` for this, and how?

Answer (score 0):

tf.gather() makes slices only along one axis, so for your case tf.gather_nd() would work better. So it should be as following:

```
# make a placeholder for indices of the outputs you will pick, 
# or make it constant if they won't change
indices = tf.placeholder(tf.int32,[None,4]) 

conv1 = tf.layers.conv2d(
    inputs=input_layer,
    filters=4,
    kernel_size=[14, 14],
    padding="valid",
    activation=tf.nn.relu
)

# select required outputs
new_input = tf.gather_nd(conv,indices)
# or you can hard-wire them, if they're constant
new_input = tf.gather_nd(conv, [[0,0,0,0],[1,0,0,0]])

# then you need to reshape it back a proper size 
# as previous operation will return flattened list 
# (unless you slice raws, but not single outputs). 
# Depending what size you got and what you need, but possibly something like that:
required_shape = [-1,10,10,4]
new_input = tf.reshape(new_input,required_shape) 
# or instead of the constant array feed a tensor with new shape as well

conv2 = tf.layers.conv2d(
    inputs=new_input,
    filters=16,
    kernel_size=[5, 5],
    padding="valid",
    activation=tf.nn.relu
)
```

In case of gather_nd you can specify explicit elements of the array along each axis. There is a good example in the official documentation:

```
indices = [[1]]
params = [[['a0', 'b0'], ['c0', 'd0']],
          [['a1', 'b1'], ['c1', 'd1']]]
output = [[['a1', 'b1'], ['c1', 'd1']]]

indices = [[0, 1], [1, 0]]
params = [[['a0', 'b0'], ['c0', 'd0']],
          [['a1', 'b1'], ['c1', 'd1']]]
output = [['c0', 'd0'], ['a1', 'b1']]

indices = [[0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1]]
params = [[['a0', 'b0'], ['c0', 'd0']],
          [['a1', 'b1'], ['c1', 'd1']]]
output = ['b0', 'b1']
```